# Node with React: How change port number to url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, url

I have a Nodejs server and within that server there is a React app. Currently I am running the server on `localhost:8000` and the React app is on `localhost:3000`. What I wanted to do is have the server be accessible through the address `localhost/server` and the app to be accessible through the address `localhost/admin/` So for example to open my app I would have to type `https://localhost/admin` and to access the server endpoints, the app would have to send requests to `https://localhost/server`. Hope I'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your apache server settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com

 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyVia Full

 ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```